# PHP MySQL Update Column Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update some columns in a row with MySQL in PHP like so:

```
$updateuser_sql = "
UPDATE `users`
SET
`HeaderPictureID` = $insertid,
`Bio` = '" . myre($_POST['Bio']) . "',
`ContactEmail` = '". myre($_POST['ContactEmail']) ."',
`PhoneNo` = '". myre($_POST['PhoneNo']) ."',
`TwitterHandle` = '". myre($_POST['TwitterHandle']) ."'
WHERE
`UserID` = '{$_SESSION['userID']}'
";

$mysqli->query($updateuser_sql);

if($mysqli->errno) {
    $handlerreturn['status'] = 'USER_UPDATE_FAILURE';
    console.log('FAILED');
} else {
    $handlerreturn['status'] = 'EXEC_SUCCESS';
    console.log('WORKED');
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get the log 'FAILED'. How can I find out, more precisely, what is wrong and work to fix the issue? Am I doing something so obviously wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `echo $mysqli->error;`?

Comment: `echo $updateuser_sql;`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I add this to the code...

Comment: o_O How? You can't to echo your SQL? Hm, what is 'console.log' ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the end of your page

```
$_POST["Bio"] = "hi";
$_POST['ContactEmail'] = "cheese";
$_POST['PhoneNo'] = "lion";
$_POST['TwitterHandle'] = "asdl";
$_SESSION['userID'] = "asdf";

$updateuser_sql = "
                    UPDATE `users`
                    SET
                    `HeaderPictureID` = 1,
                    `Bio` = '" . $_POST['Bio'] . "',
                    `ContactEmail` = '". $_POST['ContactEmail'] ."',
                    `PhoneNo` = '". $_POST['PhoneNo'] ."',
                    `TwitterHandle` = '". $_POST['TwitterHandle'] ."'
                    WHERE
                    `UserID` = '{$_SESSION['userID']}'
                    ";

echo $updateuser_sql;
```

It'll spit out the UPDATE statement that is sent to the database.  I didn't see any syntax errors from the above.  I suspect the problem has to do with your custom "myre" function.

Comment: Hi Lloyd, yes, if I put all that at the bottom it works. However, it still doesn't work in a function... The function *is* getting called though.

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 Can you post what your custom function looks like?

Comment: `"'" . $var . "'"` is not correct wrapping, also you need str_replace("'", "''", $var)

Comment: We asked for myre function, or better SQL from "if I put all that at the bottom it works"

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 Is this the same function you're using in your code?  This looks like it does something entirely different than from how the "myre" function is being used in your original question

Comment: I didn't even need the "myre" function - somebody else on my team wrote that and I'm not sure why they did because it wasn't needed :)